# zend custom router that uses a mysql db

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I am looking at writing a application that requires search engine friendly URLs for a lot of  pages. So for example to access say site.com/blah could be a user or a page. For this I was thinking of having a table where I have the URL and then I have a column with the controller, action and any parameters such as id of a page or a user.

I know a db look-up can be slow so I am wondering if this is the best way of going about things?

Comment: what's wrong with /user/blah?

Comment: I read the title as 'costume' router! I'm a bit disapointed now :)

Comment: with /user/blah the client would like to avoid it and 'costume' is a spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the same route URL (site.com/blah) for two different controller/action, the only way is to use database lookup. When a new user signs up, store the username and the user ID in the database and the route type to 'User' for this username. When a new page is created, store the page name and the page ID in the database and the route type to 'Page'.
When a URL is requested, check the name against the database and get the route type and forward accordingly.